# Postgres - INSERT INTO and using case when

Tags: sql, postgresql

I'm trying to insert a row when my CTE returns <s>null</s> false, but I can't figure out how to do it correctly

Doesnt work:

```
with cte as (SELECT EXISTS (SELECT * FROM commentsvoted WHERE id = $1 AND user_id = $2))
INSERT INTO commentsvoted = 
(CASE WHEN cte.exists IS FALSE (id, user_id, votes, thread_id) VALUES($1, 
$2, true, $3)
ELSE commentsvoted
END)
```

My cte:

```
with cte as (SELECT EXISTS (SELECT * FROM commentsvoted WHERE id = $1 AND user_id = $2))
```

What I would like to insert when case is <s>null</s> false:

```
INSERT INTO commentsvoted(id, user_id, votes, thread_id) VALUES($1, $2, true, $3)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think this is what you want:

```
WITH cte as (
      SELECT EXISTS (SELECT * FROM commentsvoted WHERE id = $1 AND user_id = $2) as flag
     )
INSERT INTO commentsvoted (id, user_id, votes, thread_id)  
   SELECT $1, $2, true, $3
   FROM cte
   WHERE NOT FLAG;
```

The CTE will not contain `NULL`, because `EXISTS` returns either true or false.

I mean, this is sort-of what you want.  You probably simply want a unique index on the table:

```
create unique index unq_commentsvoted_id_user_id on commentsvoted(id, user_id);
```

Then the database will prevent you from inserting duplicate values.

Comment: Woops! What I meant is if it equals to false